# Hadoop Number of Reducers Configuration Options Priority

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, reduce, hadoop-yarn

What are the priorities of the following 3 options for setting number of reduces? In other words, if all three are set, which one will be taken into account?

**Option1:**

```
setNumReduceTasks(2) within the application code
```

**Option2:**

```
-D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 as command line argument
```

**Option3:**

```
through $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/mapred-site.xml file

 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
  <value>2</value>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have them racked in priority order - option 1 will override 2, and 2 will override 3. In other words Option 1 will be the one used by your job in this scenario

Answer (score 4):

According to the `Hadoop - The Definitive Guide`

> The -D option is used to set the configuration property with key color to the value
>   yellow. Options specified with -D take priority over properties from the configuration
>   files. This is very useful because you can put defaults into configuration files and then
>   override them with the -D option as needed. A common example of this is setting the
>   number of reducers for a MapReduce job via -D mapred.reduce.tasks=n. This will
>   override the number of reducers set on the cluster or set in any client-side configuration
>   files.

Answer (score 0):

First Priority: Passing configuration parameters through command line (while submitting MR Application)

Second Priority: Setting configuration parameters in application code

Third Priority: It will read default parameters from multiple xml files such as core-site.xml, hadoop-env.sh, hdfs-site.xml, log4j.properties and mapred-site.xml